# How to update the create react app to its latest version?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to update the `create-react-app` to its latest version. In the docs, they have mentioned using the below command to update the react scripts to `5.0.0`.

```
sudo npm i create-react-app@5.0.0
```

I wonder if there is any way to update `create-react-app` to its latest stable released version without knowing the exact version.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Updating your an existing project build tooling is typically a daunting and time-consuming task. When new versions of Create React App are released, you can upgrade using a single command:

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

---

In most cases bumping the `react-scripts` version in `package.json` and running `npm install` (or `yarn install`) should be enough.

---

When you run `npx create-react-app my-app` it automatically installs the latest version of Create React App.

Create React App creates the project with the latest version of `react-scripts` so you’ll get all the new features and improvements in newly created apps automatically.

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you **uninstall** the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that **[npx always uses the latest version](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#quick-start)**.

Reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases